# Commit/Read offset to Zookeeper Manually

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I want to apologise if the question is not well formed so I will add additional clarifications if needed.

I have a Kafka Topic and a consumer written in Java using Spring Kafka 2.8.. I want to manually save the offsets to Zookeeper on certain period of time so another application can read them in case of a failure.
Yes, I know my consumer is committing offsets to __consumer_offsets, but I want to have it in Zookeeper as a backup plan.
Is there a way I can do that? Any link to documentation or approach will be much appreciated!

Comment: Zookeeper will be completely removed in next Kafka major release, so I would not recommend this

Answer (score 0):

Kafka moved offset storage from zookeeper to brokers for the reason of high writes load such that offset updates needed to be routed across all nodes. You can have a look at [Offset Management](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Offset+Management)

What failure are you anticipating from current offset management in place? Perhaps  you can increase `offsets.topic.replication.factor` which is the replication factor of `__consumer_offsets` topic to have higher availability.

If you want to manually commit the offsets,first `enable.auto.commit` which is `ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG` in spring should be `false` to avoid committing the offsets automatically. use `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` or `MANUAL` acknowledge mode to commit the offsets periodically [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.0-M2/reference/html/#ooo-commits).
Ideally, it is not safe for manual acknowledgment since the offsets can be committed out of order.